# select() returns only when data reaches a certain size

Tags: linux, operating-system, file-descriptor, epoll

In Linux programming, when you call select(), it unblocks as soon as there is *any* data in any of the file descriptors being monitored.  Is there a way to make it so that it unblocks only when any of the file descriptor has data that has reached a certain size?  Like, only unblocks when any fd has more than 5KB of data, etc.

How about epoll()?

Comment: Append it to a buffer and do stuff when your buffer gets to 5 KB?

Comment: Such behaviour would violate streaming protocols.  What would happen if you were using TCP to transfer a file and the last block only contained 3KB?  You would be stuck forever?